# I want to change the products I created with Advanced Custom Field to Woocommerce Product attribute

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a [site](https://www.cepkolik.com/cep-telefonu/honor-x9b/) I created using ACF Pro. There are thousands of products here. I want to change all these products to Woocommerce.

Is there a plugin that automatically matches product features as Woocommerce attributes? Or what is your suggestion?